# Need to understand the order of execution in closures

Tags: swift, closures

I've been experimenting in Playground with an example from the Swift documentation regarding closures - I added the print statements inside the incrementer function and just before returning on the makeIncrementer function.

```
func makeIncrementer(forIncrement amount: Int) -> () -> Int {
    var runningTotal = 0
    func incrementer() -> Int {
        print("something")
        runningTotal += amount

        return runningTotal
    }
    print("running total is: \(runningTotal)")
    return incrementer
}

let incrementByTen = makeIncrementer(forIncrement: 10)
incrementByTen()
incrementByTen()
incrementByTen()
incrementByTen()
incrementByTen()
incrementByTen()
```

when I run the code I get:

```
running total is: 0
something
something
something
something
something
something
```

Why isn't the "running total is:" print executed every time I call incrementByTen()? - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Executing the line `let incrementByTen = makeIncrementer(forIncrement: 10)`

  creates the function `func incrementer()` by capturing `runningTotal` and `amount`, prints `running total is..` and returns

  ```
  func incrementer() -> Int {
      print("something")
      runningTotal += 10

      return runningTotal
  }
  ```

  It does **not** execute `incrementer()`.
  After that the variable `incrementByTen` contains the entire `incrementer()` function
- Executing the line `incrementByTen()`

  executes only the function `incrementer()`, prints `something`, does the math and returns the incremented value.